# Connection strings for SQL Azure with geo-replica

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, failover

With read-only routing, we can have a Failover Group listener direct the connection to a read-only secondary automatically, which can provide additional capacity.

I have set this up but I am confused about the fact that the FG provides two different FQDNs for the connection, one is `servername.database.windows.net` and the other `servername.secondary.database.windows.net`. These work as expected when the system is up and running but what is not clear is what happens to the secondary connection if the primary goes offline and a failover takes place. Would the secondary connection automatically route to the new primary/only server or would it simply stop working because there would be no secondaries available?

I would test it but I can't find a way to take the secondary offline to simulate it being unavailable.

Alternatively. when I tried using the primary connection with `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly`, it seems it sends all traffic to the primary server so that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

> what happens to the secondary connection if the primary goes offline and a failover takes place?

Auto-failover groups provide read-write and read-only listener end-points that remain unchanged during geo-failovers. This means **you do not have to change the connection string for your application after a geo-failover**, because connections are automatically routed to the current primary. Whether you use manual or automatic failover activation, a geo-failover switches all secondary databases in the group to the primary role.

> would it simply stop working because there would be no secondaries available?

1. If you add a single database to the failover group, it automatically creates a secondary database using the same edition and compute size on secondary server.
2. If you add a database that already has a secondary database in the secondary server, that geo-replication link is inherited by the group.
3. When you add a database that already has a secondary database in a server that is not part of the failover group, a new secondary is created in the secondary server.

Refer: [Auto-failover groups overview & best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auto-failover-group-sql-db?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#auto-failover-group-capabilities)

Comment: Thanks but I do not read that page in the same way as you do. The bit about not changing connection strings is describing the read-write connection. That same section says that all secondaries are made in primaries, which doesn't correct. Further up in that document, it says "...means the read-only sessions will not be able to connect until the secondary is recovered" about the secondary listener. It then mentions "AllowReadOnlyFailoverToPrimary"